# Problems with filemanager in C#

Tags: c#, file, dialog, filenames, word-processor

What do I need to write to get this to work?

> If the current text in the text window is not saved (or is unchanged since it was opened) and you try to close, open or create a new file, the user should be asked if he / she wants to save before the new file / new document is opened. The answer options should be "yes", "no" or "cancel". Is the text unchanged, no question should come up.
>
> If the text has been changed it shall be indicated by an asterisk (*) in window title, ex. "File.txt *".
>
> Also, you should be able so save with "Save" under the current filename. 
>   And Save As to create a new file.
>
> And last: The possibility to close the current view (can also be an opened file)

Here is my code:

```
namespace filemanager
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void closeFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (textBox1.Text.Length != 0)
            {
                DialogResult answr;

                answr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save your file before closing?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

                if (answr == DialogResult.No)
                {

                    textBox1.Clear();
                    Application.ExitThread();

                }

                if (answr == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    saveFile_Click(this, e);
                }

            }

        }

        private void openFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileFunc.Title = "Open file";
            openFileFunc.InitialDirectory = "C:";
            openFileFunc.FileName = "";
            openFileFunc.Filter = "Text Document|*.txt|Word Documents|*.doc";

            string Chosen_File = "";

            if (openFileFunc.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
            {

                Chosen_File = openFileFunc.FileName;
                textBox1.LoadFile(Chosen_File, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

            }

        }

        private void saveFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            saveFileFunc.Title = "Save file";
            saveFileFunc.InitialDirectory = "C:";
            saveFileFunc.FileName = "";
            saveFileFunc.Filter = "Text Document|*.txt|Word Documents|*.doc";

            string Save_File = "";


            if (saveFileFunc.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
            {

                Save_File = saveFileFunc.FileName;
                textBox1.SaveFile(Save_File, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

            }
        }

        private void saveAs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            saveFileFunc.Title = "Save file";
            saveFileFunc.InitialDirectory = "C:";
            saveFileFunc.FileName = "";
            saveFileFunc.Filter = "Text Document|*.txt|Word Documents|*.doc";

            string Save_File = "";


            if (saveFileFunc.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
            {

                Save_File = saveFileFunc.FileName;
                textBox1.SaveFile(Save_File, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your question? Which code doesn't work?

Comment: Haha oops, I wrongly phrased myself. I don't even know how to write it. I've tried a bunch of times but all I do is messing up the code I have (that works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet of code will put you in the right direction. I leave the finalization to you.

```
    // flag for holding the Dirty state of the textbox
    private bool IsDirty = false;
    // the setter handles the showing or no showing of a * in the title
    private bool Dirty
    {
        set
        {
            IsDirty = value;
            this.Text = "TextProcessor " + (IsDirty ? "*" : "");
        }
    }

    // hookup textChanged on the (rich)textBox to trigger the Dirty flag
    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dirty = true;
    }

    // hookup the formclosing event to Cancel the closing of the form.
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsDirty)
        {
            switch (MessageBox.Show("save?", "saving", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel))
            {
                case DialogResult.Cancel:
                case DialogResult.Yes:
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

You will find enough keywords to google the additional details.

Comment: Thank you! :) this was so helpful!